# Using regexp_like in case statement for and condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these data in my table

```
emp_id   emp_sal   emp_addr
1        1000      10-jul-13
2        2000      00002000
3        3000      AMP
4        4000      10-oct-2013
5        5000      0.1122
9        9000      panna
10       1000      10-oct-13
11       1000      -60
12       1010      10-10-10
13       1010      10-10-2010
```

I want to select all data with condition that where

1. if emp_addr have date in dd-mon-yy then should come as it is.
2. if emp_addr have date in dd-mm-yy then should come in dd-mon-yy .
3. if emp_addr have number or character then default date should '31-31-2099'.

I have tried this query:-

```
select * from sunil_test 
WHERE emp_id in (1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13)
  and case when regexp_like(emp_addr
                         , '[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:alpha:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{2}') 
           then emp_addr
           when regexp_like(emp_addr
                        , '[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}') 
           then to_char(to_date(emp_addr,'dd-mm-yy'),'dd-mon-yy')
           else '31-31-99'
      end = 1
```

I have to use these condition in where clause and using SQL only not PLSQL.

Comment: You should be using that CASE in your select clause and not where clause.

Comment: What Eat A Peach said.  You need to have the case statement in your select statement, not your WHERE clause.

Comment: I do not understand what you need? I mean you want to select just only **emp_addr**=**1** records?

Comment: I am using character column inside my where clause so while comparing if records inside column are date then they should come as it is and for other a default date sholud come.  Basically i am not sure how to use case statement inside where clause.